# mount error 13 centos 7

Tags: centos, mount, windows

I have a folder hosted on a (brace yourself) Windows Server (2008) and I need CentOS to be able to read files from it. I am currently using this command:

```
$ sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/dev-admin/credentials.txt,uid=1000 //192.168.1.123/folder /mnt/win
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I've done some googling, and found a few posts with possible solutions, I've tried adding the `sec` option to the mount command, testing every available option but all return either messages along the lines of `Invalid option` or `Permission Denied`.

`/var/log/messages` doesn't show anything the above error message doesn't. The only thing worth noting is `NT_STATUS_LOGIN_FAILURE` but I've triple and quadruple-checked the credentials and it works (copied and pasted into remote desktop on another Windows machine and it works)

So I guess my question, is, what's wrong with my command and how do I debug this?

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer, and after a grace period of some hours, you can accept it as valid. Otherwise, this question is likely to be closed and eventually deleted as "went away on its own or when a typo was fixed".

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I'll post as answer, as could be a gentle reminder to people to double check details, thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it. Always double check ip addr, and I also had to add `vers=2.1` to my `-o` param otherwise I'd get `Remote I/O error` so full string is now:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o credentials=/home/dev-admin/credentials.txt,uid=1000,vers=2.1 //192.168.1.124/folder /mnt/win
```